# List sorting in Snowflake as part of the select

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

lets assume im having to following query

```
select column1, count(*) from (values ('a'), ('b'), ('ab'), ('ba')) group by 1;

COLUMN1 COUNT(*)
a   1
b   1
ba  1
ab  1
```

and I want that my grouping will be order insensitive means that I want to count `ab` and `ba` as the same value.
so the expected result will be

```
COLUMN1 COUNT(*)
a   1
b   1
ab  2
```

I thought about sorting the select so it will handle them both as the same value but I didnt find any option to sort the value in snowflake.

Comment: What about abc or cba or acb?

Comment: @gargsms same, abc == cba == acb (insensitivity to the content)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There may be a way to do this in a SQL, but a JavaScript UDF makes it easy:

```
create or replace function SORT_STRING(TEXT string)
returns string
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
    return TEXT.split('').sort().join('');
$$;

select SORT_STRING(column1) SORTED_C1, count(*) 
from (values ('a'), ('b'), ('ab'), ('ba')) group by 1;
```

| SORTED_C1 | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| ab | 2 |

Comment: thanks, it totally did the trick I looked for, I wasnt aware to the fact that those sql/js udfs exists (lack of permissions in the org) but now that I do, it will be much easier. p.s fixed the tagging.

Comment: @GregPavlik  Definitely possible with SQL only :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is expressive enough to achieve this effect without using JS/Java/Python functions.

Preparation - rearranging input string:

```
SELECT column1, seq,
       LISTAGG(sub.value) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sub.value) AS sorted_column1
FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('ab'), ('ba')) AS src
,TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(column1, '(.)', '\\1~'), '~'), '~')) AS sub
GROUP BY column1, seq;
```

Output:

| COLUMN1 | SORTED_COLUMN1 |
| --- | --- |
| ba | ab |
| b | b |
| ab | ab |
| a | a |

---

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT src.column1, sub.seq, 
         LISTAGG(sub.value) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sub.value) AS sorted_column1
  FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('ab'), ('ba')) AS src
  ,TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(column1,'(.)', '\\1~'),'~'),'~')) AS sub
  GROUP BY src.column1, sub.seq
)
SELECT sorted_column1, COUNT(*)
FROM cte
GROUP BY sorted_column1;
```

Output:

| SORTED_COLUMN1 | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| ab | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| a | 1 |